# Trigger GUI without OnClick (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile, virtual-reality

Is there a way to trigger an event without OnClick function? I wanted to make a Cardboard VR game where the player can teleport to a location just by looking at a spot for a specific amount of time. Like the player will look at a circle for 3secs and it will teleport the player in the said circle.

I haven't tried anything because I'm new to Unity...

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. I don't know exactly how Cardboard VR works but e.g. with HoloLens (1) you always had this head pointer.

So you could rely on [`IPointerEnterHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html)/[`IPointerExitHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerExitHandler.html) and expose some [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityEvents.html)s (basically what e.g. `Button.onClick` or `InputField.onValueChanged` is). And then use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) do something like e.g.

```
public void TimedTrigger : MonoBehaviour, IPonterEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public float duration = 2f;

    public UnityEvent onCompleted;
    public UnityEvent<float> onProgress;

    private Coroutine routine;

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        routine = StartCoroutine(Routine());
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        if(routine != null) StopCoroutine(routine);
    }

    private IEnumerator Routine()
    {
        for(var time = 0f; time < duration; time += Time.deltaTime)
        {
            var progress = Mathf.Clamp01(time / duration);
            onProgress.Invoke(progress);
            yield return null;
        }

        routine = null;
        onProgress.Invoke(1f);
        onCompleted.Invoke();
    }
}
```

This will expose two events to the Inspector (similar to `Button.onClick`) you can hook up methods to

- `OnCompleted` - pretty self-explanatory - is called **once** after the object was focused for `duration` seconds

  Here you want to trigger the same behavior as in `onClick`. If this is really about actual `UI.Button`s you could even trigger the actual `onClick` of the button here (so you don't have to hook up all listeners twice everywhere)

  ```
  GetComponent<Button>().onClick.Invoke(); // should cache the reference of course
  ```
- `OnProgress` - also self-explanatory - is called **each frame** during a focus process. The passed `float` shows the progress from `0` to `1`

  Can be used e.g. to show he user some visual feedback (e.g. an Image with circular fill around the head pointer is what we used to use)

**Note**: For the `IPointerXYHandler` interfaces to work

- You need an [`EventSystem`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.html) in your scene
- The component implementing the interfaces

  - either has to be on the same object as a `UnityEngine.UI.Gaphic` (e.g. `Image`, `Text` etc) with `Raycast Target` set to `true`
  - or on a 3D/2D object with according [Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html)/[Collider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html)

    in this case you additionally need a [`PhysicsRaycaster`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PhysicsRaycaster.html)/[`Physics2DRaycaster`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Physics2DRaycaster.html) component attached to your `Camera` and enabled according target layers